# Understanding the flow for Log in with Paypal using Identity API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am implementing Log in with Paypal on my Job portal application developed in ASP.net MVC. The flow will be below -

1. Freelancer will add the Paypal account to his profile.
2. We will display Login with Paypal button.
3. Once login is successful, we will try to retrieve the Paypal account status and email address.
4. If the Paypal account is verified, we will do the automatic payments to the freelancer once task owner approves the task.

I am following below article -

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/integrate/

Below are my questions -

1. In the section "Enable Log in with PayPal", what is the return_url ? How it will give me information of the user i.e. authorization code  ? Is there a sample url.
2. In the section "Get access token" we need to pass authorization code, how should I get the authorization code.
3. How will I get the user information in the section "Get Customer info".

Can someone please explain me how this works and how I can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The Return URL is your URL. You specify and configure it. You wait at least 3 hours after doing so before using it.

The authorization code is returned as part of the URL. You use it in Identity API requests to get the information fields specified by the scopes. This is covered in the document.